# TWO dynamic dropdowns with ONE model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I have a search field where I want to add two dropdowns that should help me filter my search results. In my database I have one **Product** model with two columns, named **country** and **type**.

The first dropdown should filter by country and the second should filter by type. However, I am trying to set the second dropdown dynamically meaning that depending on the first dropdown (country) only those types should be displayed in the second dropdown that match the respective country selected. If possible this behavior should also work the other way around i.e. depending on the type, only matching countries should be displayed.

I've been trying several tutorials that work with more than one model however, I didn't manage to get it to work with only one model. My code for the dropdown selections is the following:

```
<%= form_tag("filter", :id => "filter_form", :method => "post") do %>
<label for="country" class="country">Country</label> <%=  select_tag :country, options_for_select(Product.pluck(:country).uniq), { include_blank: 'Select country' }%>
<label for="type" class="type">Type</label> 
<%=  select_tag :type, options_for_select(Product.pluck(:type).uniq),{ include_blank: "Alle Kategorien" }%>
```

1. Is is possible with only one model?
2. Do I need AJAX for this or is Javascrip/jQuery sufficient?

Thank you very much!

Comment: 1. probably 2. javascript-only will only work if you preload all the product-data into the javascript and then filter on that within the javascript. This is possible, but imagine in the future when you have 50,000 Products in your table... cumbersome :( AJAX sending a request to your app is probably a bit more future-proof

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know any beginner guide for AJAX for rails you can recommend? I am completely new on this topic :S

Comment: My go-to is always the Rails Guides... and there's one on Javascript (inc AJAX): http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html I don't think I've used it so can't say how good it is, but the Rails Guides are usually well worth your time.